# array of arrays to be combined if containing matching object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have list of objects, (the list could be a set, a mutable array, etc) using pseudo code to explain what I am trying to do...

```
 @[ @[1, 2, 3], @[2, 5, 6], @[8, 9] ]; // the numbers are NSObjects, using numbers here for simplicity.
```

How can I combine items that contain 1 or more matching item:

```
@[ @[1, 2, 3, 5, 6], @[8, 9] ];
```

(1, 2, 3 are combined with 5, 6 because they both contain '2').

I am asking this question in a way that hopefully opens up a wider scope for suggested solutions, as someone might know a technique to do this that I haven't come across.

Comment: What do you mean "the numbers could be NSObjects" - you can only store objects within `NSArray`s or any other Objective-C collection class.

Comment: I've updated the question. Is it clearer?

Comment: How many objects and how many arrays do you expect to have? There are at least two ways of doing it - a simple but slow, and an extremely fast but somewhat complicated. The choice depends on the size of the problem.

Comment: I think you'd be better served with an NSSet than an NSArray

Comment: I'll give NSSet a go and see what I can do with unionSet and intersectSet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches that you can take - a simple and straightforward one that works fine for a small number of objects, or an advanced one that works fine even for extremely large sets of objects.

The first approach uses a simple algorithm that starts with your initial array, copies its inner arrays into `NSSet`s, and examines each pair of sets for presence of common items. You can do it with the `intersectsSet:` method. If a pair of sets has common elements, replace it with a union of the sets. Use `setByAddingObjectsFromSet:` for that. Each time that two sets are merged, set a special flag that says that the collection of sets has been modified. If upon examining all pairs of sets you see that this flag is set, replace the prior array of sets with the modified one, and start the pairwise checking from scratch. Since each step that sets the flag reduces the number of sets at least by one, this loop is guaranteed to finish. Once the loop has finished, convert an array of sets to an array of arrays.

The second approach is more complex, but it is also much faster. Construct a [*disjoint-set data structure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), add elements of each array to it, and then go through the original arrays again, examining the sets in which each of their elements has ended up. When two elements are in the same set, put them into the same array.

Comment: Nice idea with the disjoint-set. More precisely you need to iterate over the arrays, then of each array add all of its objects to the disjoint-set structure and "union" ("merge", "connect", "join", whatever you call the operation) each element with the first element of its array (thus merging all of the array's elements). All can be done in almost linear time.

Comment: @VadimYelagin Correct, the official name of that operation is "union". I needed to implement this data structure once, it wasn't that bad, and it worked amazingly fast.

Comment: Yeah, I loved implementing it some years ago too. Very little code, though "inverse Ackermann function amortized time per operation" sounds kick-ass :-)

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm doing what you wanted. But its might not be the best optimised way.

```
-(void)doSomeWork{
    NSMutableArray *arr =  [@[ @[@1, @2, @3], @[@4, @5, @6], @[@8, @9]] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"abc = %@",arr);
    for(int i=0; i<arr.count;i++){
        NSArray *subArray = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
        for(int j=0; j<subArray.count;j++){
            for(int k=0; k<arr.count;k++)
                if(i==k){
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    if([[arr objectAtIndex:k]containsObject:[subArray objectAtIndex:j]]){
                        [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[self addCommonObjectsFrom:[arr objectAtIndex:i] arr2:[arr objectAtIndex:k]]];
                        [arr removeObject:[arr objectAtIndex:k]];

                    }
                }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"abc = %@",arr);
}

-(NSArray*)addCommonObjectsFrom:(NSArray*)arr1 arr2:(NSArray*)arr2{
    NSMutableSet *set1 = [[NSMutableSet alloc]initWithArray:arr1];
    [set1 addObjectsFromArray:arr2];
    return [set1 allObjects];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Parser, I think this solves my question, lots to learn from going through your code. Thank you.

Comment: @IanClay If you any doubt in understanding the code you can ask me.

Comment: Not to mention the terrible ineffectiveness, there is probably a bug: you should decrement `k` after you remove the k-th element. Because after you remove it the (k+1)-th element with become the k-th, the k will get incremented, and the element will be skipped. Also, it should be `removeObjectAtIndex:`, since there can be duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of an algorithm what you need is to find [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) (algorithms for that are found by following the link) of a [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) with one set of vertices for your arrays and another set of vertices for your numbers, with edges connecting each array with each of its elements.

Then for each component you create a set of numbers consisting of all the numbers corresponding to the second set of vertices.

There probably can be no notion of preserving the ordering of the elements from the input arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A MUCH cleaner approach is to use sets, and simply test if the sets intersect.  See [NSSet intersectsSet].

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I wrote using a variation of @dasblinkenlight tips.

```
  NSMutableArray *compareSets = [NSMutableArray new];
  NSMutableArray *t =   [@[ @[@1, @2, @3],@[@12,@13,@14,@15,@16], @[@2, @5, @6], @[ @8, @9], @[@10, @2, @9], @[@11,@12222], @[@123, @34, @342, @1000], @[@34, @10001]  ] mutableCopy] ;
   for (NSArray *m in t) {
    NSMutableSet *b = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:m];
    [compareSets addObject:b];
   }

 int reRunSet = 0;
 int runStore = 0;
 while (true) {
    int setCount = compareSets.count;

    if (setCount == 1) {
        break;
    }

    runStore = (int) setCount;
    for (int i = (runStore - 1); i > 0; i--) {
         if ( [compareSets[0] intersectsSet:compareSets[i]] ) {
            setCount++;
            [compareSets[i] unionSet:compareSets[0]];

            [compareSets removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        }
    }

    NSMutableSet *t = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    [t setSet:compareSets[0]];

    [compareSets removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [compareSets addObject:t];
    if (runStore != setCount) {
        reRunSet = 0;
        continue;
    }

    if (setCount == compareSets.count) {
        reRunSet ++;
        if (reRunSet == setCount) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"compared sets finish = %@", compareSets);
```